# Convert timestamp to datetimefield and save it in the database

Tags: django

Suppose i have a time stamp as following:

```
ts=1549366296466
```

and i have a model which has DateTimeField as follows:

```
class MyTime(models.Model):
    date_and_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now suppose that there is an object 'o' of class 'MyTime' ? How can i use this time stamp and save it into object 'o'?

```
o.date_and_time = #I need your help here.
o.save()
```

I know how to convert this into 'Date Time' format.I can do this using the below method.

```
import datetime

#First i will convert timestamp into seconds format by dividing by 1000.0
ts = ts/1000.0
#Then i will use this 'ts' in the following line of code.
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datetime` ojbect has a [`.utcfromtimestamp` method [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp). The only difference is that this timestamp measures the number of seconds since 1970, not the number of milliseconds, so we can convert this with:

```py
from datetime import datetime

o.date_and_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts/1000)
```

This gives us the following two results:

```
2019-02-05 11:31:36.466000
```

or for a custom timezone, we can use [`.fromtimestamp` method [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```py
from dateutil import tz
from datetime import datetime

o.date_and_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts/1000, tz=tz.gettz('Asia/Kolkata'))
```

This then yields:

```
2019-02-05 17:01:36.466000+05:30
```

Comment: Sir @WillemVanOnsem , I am getting wrong timings though date is right. If you need to know my details then I live in India and timezone is 'Asia/Kolkata'

Comment: @AshokKumar: then you should use `.fromtimestamp(..)` and set `tz=...` to the correct one, see edit.