# How to convert from time stamp to a date time filed in dajngo

Tags: python, django, database, rest

I 'm working on a django app and i have a model with a datetimefield and in my view i accept data in json format which has date in time stamp , when i try to save the date in my model i get this error

```
"Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]."
```

i tried to use this with no help :

```
date_converted_to_date_time_field = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(due_in_time_stamp )
```

my view looks like that :

```
 @api_view(['POST', ]) 
 def todo_list_api_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    due_in_time_stamp = int(request.data["due"])
    date_converted_to_date_time_field = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(due_in_time_stamp ) # i pass it to a serializer to save the data in a model like that  

    serializer = mySerializer(data=request.data , context = {'user':request.user , 'due_date' : date_converted_to_date_time_field})
```

any help to achieve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert timestamp to datetimefield and save it in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533772/convert-timestamp-to-datetimefield-and-save-it-in-the-database)

Comment: Please share an example of the JSON time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem example of my json time "date" : "1627656615"

Comment: Your problem does not appear to be in the code you've shown here. Your `date_converted...` variable will contain a Python `datetime` instance - what do you do with it after that?

Comment: i pass it to deserialize these values and create a new  instance in db @PeterDeGlopper

Comment: I think you'll need to show your serializer code. My suspicion is that it's trying to deserialize the datetime as if it were a string representation - a good default assumption but not the situation you're in - but that's just a guess.

Comment: Or, for that matter, possibly still trying to convert the `due` value in your request data rather than the datetime. That'd give you the error that you're reporting.

Answer (score 0):

due = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

due=serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d",input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d',])

Comment: my model has a due with a field datetimefield not datefield , thanks